# Using a custom template for a custom button on kendo ui editor

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a custom button for the kendo ui editor. The button works fine except when I try to use a custom template.

Here's the code for my custom button:

```
var currentDateAction = {
    name: 'currentDate',
    tooltip: vm.TemplateLetterCurrentDateLabel(),
    template: '<button class="k-button">' + vm.TemplateLetterCurrentDateLabel() + '</button>',
    exec: function () {
        var editor = $(this).data('kendoEditor');
        editor.exec('inserthtml', { value: vm.TemplateLetterCurrentDate() });
    }
};
```

If I comment the template line, the button works, otherwise it doesn't.

What do I have to do, to have a custom template for my button?

Comment: if you remove the vm.TemplateLetterCurrentDateLabel() does that work?